# How do i run a timer in a function , using python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code:

```
def Transalted_Content(content):

driver= webdriver.Chrome("H:\\CI\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://translate.shell.com/')

translate_from = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.form-control#translateText")))
translate_from._parent.execute_script("""
var elm = arguments[0], text = arguments[1];
if (!('value' in elm))
  throw new Error('Expected an <input> or <textarea>');
elm.focus();
elm.value = text;
elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
""", translate_from, content)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#translate").click()

time.sleep(3.5)                                   

translated_text_element= driver.find_element_by_id('translatedText')
translated_text=translated_text_element.get_attribute('value')

driver.close()

return translated_text
```

Sometimes chrome gets timed out, So is there a way i can write a while loop as a function separately and run it parallel whenever this function is called so that it can execute a:

```
 driver.refresh()
```

and can keep doing this at a time interval(if it exceeds a time interval)?

Comment: @debanjanB Sorry, i will do so.

Comment: @DebanjanB can you help me out with this too :)

Comment: Can you help me to understand your _usecase_ why you need a timer? At which line does `chrome gets timed out`? Can you update the question with the exact _steps_ you are trying to _automate_?

Comment: You need to fix the indentation in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a function in parallel to another using the `threading` module

```
import threading

def my_threaded_function():
    sleep(0.5)

thread = threading.Thread(target=my_threaded_function)
thread.start()
```

Arguments can be passed to your function by using the `args` parameter or by using a lambda expression to wrap your function.

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=my_threaded_function, args=['arg1', 'arg2'])
```

Or

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: my_threaded_function('arg1', 'arg2'))
```